# mathematical representation in html

Tags: html

I have some mathematical functions for notations have to represent for example:
 a^2 + b^2  = c^2

I tried the following it rendered as

`a 2 + b 2 = c 2`

instead of

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QCkV.jpg)

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <head>
     <title>MathML in HTML5</title>
   </head>
 <body>

   <math>
     <mrow>
       <mrow>
    <msup>
      <mi>a</mi>
      <mn>2</mn>
    </msup>
    <mo>+</mo>
    <msup>
      <mi>b</mi>
      <mn>2</mn>
    </msup>
  </mrow>
  <mo>=</mo>
  <msup>
    <mi>c</mi>
    <mn>2</mn>
  </msup>
</mrow>
   </math>
```

I followed this one:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/MathML/Element/math#Examples

is there a way other than this to use mathematical representation in html format in modern browsers?

Comment: Please try to add as much detail as possible to help us understand what was expected. How did this render? How did you expect it to render? If you have further questions please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: https://www.mathjax.org/

Comment: From above, you need to import mathjax (which is what it seems to be using). On the getting started page there is a script reference which looks... promising? just explore

Comment: that worked neatly. thank you.

Comment: Your code works for me. I am using Firefox 59 on OSX. What browser are you using?

Comment: chrome latest and edge browser.